# Why is QGIS graphical modeler modal?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, modal

I often switch between graphical modeler and the main QGIS application and wonder why I am not able to operate QGIS when modeler window is open. Saving my models and closing / reopening modeler annoys me, so...

- Is the a deeper reason for modeler being modal?
- Is there a simple way to turn off this behaviour (python console)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good news is that it's been fixed for QGIS 3.0.